# ui-router doesn't route to $urlRouterProvider.otherwise when html5Mode is enabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'll try to put this in a very simple way.


Here's the route file for reference:

```
angular
        .module("app")
        .config(function($stateProvider,$locationProvider,$urlRouterProvider){

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("dashboard");

            $stateProvider
                    .state("home",{
                        url: "/",
                        templateUrl: "views/home/home.html"
                    })

                    .state("login",{
                        url: "/login",
                        templateUrl: "views/login/login.html"
                    })

                    .state("home.dashboard",{
                        url: "dashboard",
                        templateUrl: "views/home/dashboard.html"
                    });       
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Now, when I comment `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`, route goes to `dashboard` normally. This is the URL `http://localhost/#/dashboard`. 
But when I try to use the `html5Mode(with <base href="/"> tag set in index.html`, it doesn't route to `dashboard`. Instead it routes to `home.html`. This is what I get `http://localhost/`. (home.html get loaded, not dashboard.html)

I really want to know why it routes successfully to `dashboard` when html5Mode is commented and why it doesn't when un-commented 
Please community help me.

Comment: did you try adding an "/" in front of the dashboard in the state .state("home.dashboard",{
                        url: "/dashboard",
                        templateUrl: "views/home/dashboard.html"
                    });

Comment: that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

[When html5Mode is enabled](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-router-html5mode?file=home%2Fhome.config.js), it means URL rewriting for relative links.

This must solve the problem, (**prefix dashboard url with** `/`)

```
.state("home.dashboard",{
  url: "/dashboard",
  templateUrl: "views/home/dashboard.html"
});
```

This is another approached (passing an object and setting `requireBase` to `false` ):

```
.state("home.dashboard",{
  url: "dashboard",
  templateUrl: "views/home/dashboard.html"
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enable: true, requireBase: false })
```